# Node.js local-web-server: can't find module ws (installed globally)

Tags: node.js, windows, webserver, local-web-server

I want to start a simple local webserver for local development on Windows 7. For this I installed node.js and then ran:

```
npm install -g local-web-server
```

Next I went to the folder `D:\[path_to_webcontent]` containing the `index.html`, started a cmd-prompt from that folder and ran:

```
node ws
```

and get the error:

> module.js:338
>
> throw err;
>
> ^    Error: Cannot find module 'D:[path_to_webcontent]\ws'

Why can't node find the globally installed webserver?
The module "local-web-server" is located at `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `node ws` you just type `ws`in the cmd-prompt.

From the documentation on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server):

```
$ npm install -g local-web-server
$ ws
```

When you write `node ws` node is looking to run a module called `ws`. When you want to use a globally installed package you just need to use the package's name in the cmd-prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you used referencing module like this and nodejs can't find 
module path, 
try:

C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

and set the full path in require path or copy ws module folder inside your project folder

var ws= require('ws')

also you can use ../ before module to go one folder up. (relative path)

(remember to mark as answered and vote up ;) 
if you got the answer)

Comment: I don't want to reference the module, I want to run it. Since it was installed globally it should be available/startable from anywhere on the system.